# Undefined reference gcc

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, compilation

When I try to compile my program on ubuntu using gcc, i get these errors:

> main.c:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `json_parse'
>   main.c:(.text+0x182): undefined reference to`json_value_free'

However, these functions are included in a file called json.h, which I import in main.c and which I include in my gcc command.

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not compile the "json.h" header. The undefined reference is *not* a compiler error, it's a *linker error*. It means you have either not compiled the file containing json_value_free to your code, or haven't linked to the library containing it. You should do either action instead of trying to compile the header file itself.

So, if you have a separate json.c file, you have to compile and link it also to your main.c file. Try (I assume GCC):

```
gcc -o myprog main.c json.c
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't make myself clear: I'm trying to compile main.c. The thing is, that the json.h file is not in a library. It's just an .h (and .c) file that I import and include..

Comment: I understand. See my further explanation.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! (Can and will accept your answer in four minutes)