# undefined reference to ... - linking issues?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, compiler-errors, undefined-reference

I don't know what I'm getting the following error:

```
proc1.o: In function `procEx1':
/cygdrive/c/armprojects/projekt/motor/proc1.c:45: undefined reference to `motorTest_test'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main.hex] Error 1
```

I've checked the following threads on this issue:

- [Undefined reference gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233078/undefined-reference-gcc)
- [Why am I getting a gcc "undefined reference" error trying to create shared objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140494/why-am-i-getting-a-gcc-undefined-reference-error-trying-to-create-shared-objec)

This is my output:

```
13:46:46 **** Build of configuration Default for project motor ****
make all 
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/armprojects/projekt/motor/startup'
rm -f .depend 
arm-elf-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi  -I . -DEL -DGCC   -mthumb-interwork -DLPC2148  -Os -    gdwarf-2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wimplicit -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wswitch     -Wreturn-type  -Wa,-ahlms=consol.lst -o consol.o consol.c
arm-elf-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi  -I . -DEL -DGCC   -mthumb-interwork -DLPC2148  -Os -    gdwarf-2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wimplicit -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wswitch -Wreturn-type  -Wa,-ahlms=framework.lst -o framework.o framework.c
framework.c: In function 'exceptionHandlerInit':
framework.c:201: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness
arm-elf-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi  -I . -DEL -DGCC   -mthumb-interwork -DLPC2148  -x           assembler-with-cpp -gstabs -Wa,-alhms=startup.lst -o startup.o startup.S
arm-elf-ar cr libea_startup_thumb.a consol.o framework.o startup.o
arm-elf-ranlib libea_startup_thumb.a
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/armprojects/projekt/motor/startup'
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/armprojects/projekt/motor/LCD'
rm -f .depend 
arm-elf-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi  -I . -DEL -DGCC   -mthumb-interwork -DLPC2148  -O0 -    gdwarf-2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wimplicit -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wswitch     -Wreturn-type  -Wa,-ahlms=LCD.lst -o LCD.o LCD.c
arm-elf-ar cr lib_LCD.a LCD.o 
arm-elf-ranlib lib_LCD.a
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/armprojects/projekt/motor/LCD'
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/armprojects/projekt/motor/interrupt'
rm -f .depend 
arm-elf-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi  -I . -DEL -DGCC   -mthumb-interwork -DLPC2148  -Os -    gdwarf-2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wimplicit -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wswitch     -Wreturn-type  -Wa,-ahlms=interrupt_timer.lst -o interrupt_timer.o interrupt_timer.c
arm-elf-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi  -I . -DEL -DGCC   -mthumb-interwork -DLPC2148  -Os -    gdwarf-2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wimplicit -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wswitch     -Wreturn-type  -Wa,-ahlms=interrupt_tacho.lst -o interrupt_tacho.o interrupt_tacho.c
arm-elf-ar cr lib_interrupt.a interrupt_timer.o interrupt_tacho.o 
arm-elf-ranlib lib_interrupt.a
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/armprojects/projekt/motor/interrupt'
rm -f .depend 
arm-elf-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi -mthumb-interwork -I./startup -DEL -DGCC -mthumb-interwork     -mthumb -DTHUMB_CSTART -DTHUMB_INTERWORK -mthumb-interwork -DLPC2148  -O0 -gdwarf-2 -Wall -    Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wimplicit -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wswitch -Wreturn-type      -Wa,-ahlms=main.lst -o main.o main.c
arm-elf-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi -mthumb-interwork -I./startup -DEL -DGCC -mthumb-interwork     -mthumb -DTHUMB_CSTART -DTHUMB_INTERWORK -mthumb-interwork -DLPC2148  -O0 -gdwarf-2 -Wall -    Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wimplicit -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wswitch -Wreturn-type      -Wa,-ahlms=proc1.lst -o proc1.o proc1.c
motor/motor_test.h:18: warning: 'duty1' defined but not used
motor/motor_test.h:19: warning: 'duty2' defined but not used
arm-elf-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi -mthumb-interwork -I./startup -DEL -DGCC -mthumb-interwork     -mthumb -DTHUMB_CSTART -DTHUMB_INTERWORK -mthumb-interwork -DLPC2148  -O0 -gdwarf-2 -Wall -    Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wimplicit -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wswitch -Wreturn-type      -Wa,-ahlms=proc2.lst -o proc2.o proc2.c
arm-elf-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi -mthumb-interwork -I./startup -DEL -DGCC -mthumb-interwork     -mthumb -DTHUMB_CSTART -DTHUMB_INTERWORK -mthumb-interwork -DLPC2148  -O0 -gdwarf-2 -Wall -    Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wimplicit -Wnested-externs -Wpointer-arith -Wswitch -Wreturn-type      -Wa,-ahlms=proc3.lst -o proc3.o proc3.c
arm-elf-gcc main.o proc1.o proc2.o proc3.o  startup/libea_startup_thumb.a     pre_emptive_os/pre_emptive_os.a LCD/lib_LCD.a interrupt/lib_interrupt.a -I./startup -    mcpu=arm7tdmi -mthumb-interwork -mthumb-interwork -nostartfiles -T     build_files/link_32k_512k_rom.ld -o main.elf -Wl,-Map=main.map,--cref
proc1.o: In function `procEx1':
/cygdrive/c/armprojects/projekt/motor/proc1.c:45: undefined reference to     `motorTest_test'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main.hex] Error 1

13:46:52 Build Finished (took 6s.46ms)
```

If you want to you could checkout my repository at:
http://dt3-robotlego-2012ht-white.googlecode.com/svn/branches/motor/Project12/

Here's some of my code (the relevant parts):

proc1.c

```
/*
 * proc1.c
 *
 *  Created on: 31 okt 2011
 *      Author: Tommy
 */

/*****************************************************************************
 * Process 1
 ****************************************************************************/
#include "pre_emptive_os/api/osapi.h"
#include "general.h"
#include "startup/lpc2xxx.h"
#include "startup/printf_P.h"
#include "startup/ea_init.h"
#include "startup/consol.h"
#include "startup/config.h"
#include "startup/framework.h"
#include "utils/utils.h"
#include "LCD/LCD.h"
#include "motor/motor_test.h"

extern long const delayshort;
extern long const delaylong;

extern tCntSem mutexLCD;

/*****************************************************************************
 * Function prototypes
 ****************************************************************************/
void LCD_clearDisplay(void);

/****************************************************************************/

void
procEx1(void* arg)
{
  tU8 error;

    for (;;) {  // QUESTION: why use for-loop?

        osSemTake(&mutexLCD, 0, &error);

        // REMARK: doesn't work at the moment... issues including runPwm()
        motorTest_test();

        osSemGive(&mutexLCD, &error);

        osSleep(100);
    }

}

void LCD_clearDisplay(void) {
    delay(delayshort);
    send_instruction(1);    //clears the display
    delay(delaylong);
    send_instruction(2);    //the cursor is moved to the first position
}
```

motor_test.h

```
/******************************************************************************
 * Includes
 *****************************************************************************/
#include "motor.h"

/******************************************************************************
 * Defines
 *****************************************************************************/
#define TASK                9       // task 1 - use circulary loop
                                    // task 2 - use constant PWM signal
                                    // ...
#define RUN_SETPWM_IN_LOOP  1       // dictates whether setPwmDutyPercentx(tU32) should be run outside the "TASK conditional statement"

/*****************************************************************************
 * Global variables
 ****************************************************************************/
static tU32 duty1;
static tU32 duty2;


/******************************************************************************
 * Prototypes
 *****************************************************************************/
void motorTest_test();
void dev_run(tU32 duty1, tU32 duty2);
void pwm_motor_init();
void pwm_motor_run(tU32 duty1, tU32 duty2);
void change_mode(short mode);
```

motor_test.c

```
#include "motor_test.h"

/******************************************************************************
 * Functions
 *****************************************************************************/
void motorTest_test() {
    init();
    dev_run(duty1, duty2);
}



// dev function - not used in release
// COMMENT: PWM signal is continuously generated when the setPwmDutyPercent(tU32) function is called, no need to endlessly iterate the calls
// EDIT:    seems like you need to iterate over the setPwmDutyPercent(tU32) functions afterall...
// COMMENT: the duty sets the speed of the motor driver
//          the value that can be set is 0-10000
//          a higher value means a lower speed, conversely a low value means a higher speed
void dev_run(tU32 duty1, tU32 duty2) {
    //wait 10 ms
    //delayMs(10);

    //wait 100 ms
    //delayMs(100);

    // COMMENT: try running without delays
    //          seems to work fine..

    while (1) {

        //set frequency value
        if (RUN_SETPWM_IN_LOOP == 1) {
            setPwmDutyPercent1(duty1);
            setPwmDutyPercent2(duty2);
        }

        //  delayMs(10);

        switch (TASK) {
        case 1: {
            //update duty cycle (0.00 - 100.00%, in steps of 0.10%)
            duty1 += 10;
            if (duty1 > 10000)
                duty1 = 0;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            duty1 = 0;
            duty2 = 8500;
            // COMMENT: slowest speed = 8500 duty
            //          fastest speed = 0    duty
            break;
        }
        case 3: { // left
            duty1 = 6000;
            duty2 = 8000;
            break;
        }
        case 4: { // right
            duty1 = 8000;
            duty2 = 6000;
            break;
        }
        case 5: {
            duty1 = 6000;
            duty2 = 6000;
            break;
        }

        case 6: {
            short delay = 1;
            short duty_vals = 6000;
            short section[3] = { 1, 0, 0 };

            if (section[0] == 1) {
                setMode1(MODE_FORWARD);
                setMode2(MODE_FORWARD);
                duty1 = duty_vals;
                duty2 = duty_vals;
                setPwmDutyPercent1(duty1);
                setPwmDutyPercent2(duty2);
                //delayMs(0);
                delay_millis(delay);
            }

            if (section[1] == 1) {
                setMode1(MODE_BRAKE);
                setMode2(MODE_BRAKE);
                setPwmDutyPercent1(duty1);
                setPwmDutyPercent2(duty2);
                delay_millis(delay);
            }

            if (section[2] == 1) {
                setMode1(MODE_REVERSE);
                setMode2(MODE_REVERSE);
                duty1 = duty_vals;
                duty2 = duty_vals;
                setPwmDutyPercent1(duty1);
                setPwmDutyPercent2(duty2);
                delay_millis(delay);
            }
            break;
        }
        case 7: {
            pwm_motor_init();
            duty1 = 6000;
            duty2 = 6000;

            //delayMs(10);
            delay_millis(10);

            pwm_motor_run(duty1, duty2);
            break;
        }
        case 8: {


            setMode1(MODE_FORWARD);
            setMode2(MODE_FORWARD);

            delay_millis(700);

            duty1 = 7000;
            duty2 = 7000;


            setMode1(MODE_REVERSE);
            setMode2(MODE_REVERSE);

            delay_millis(700);

            duty1 = 1000;
            duty2 = 1000;

            break;
        }

        case 9: {
            duty1 = 0;
            duty2 = 0;
            break;
        }

        }
    }
}

/*****************************************************************************
 * Temporary developer functions
 ****************************************************************************/
void pwm_motor_init() {
    setMode1(MODE_FORWARD);
    setMode2(MODE_FORWARD);

    delay_millis(10);
}

void pwm_motor_run(tU32 duty1, tU32 duty2) {
    setPwmDutyPercent1(duty1);
    setPwmDutyPercent2(duty2);

    while(1) {
        change_mode(MODE_FORWARD);
        change_mode(MODE_BRAKE);
        change_mode(MODE_REVERSE);
        change_mode(MODE_BRAKE);
    }
}

void change_mode(short mode) {
    setMode1(mode);
    setMode2(mode);
    delay_millis(10);
}
```

Comment: You don't want to include the file motor_test.c into the shared object?

Comment: There is no `motorTest_test()` defined anywhere in your sources in that repository.

Comment: I don't see `motor_test.o` in your command line for linking. If it's not linked in, that explains the problem...

Comment: @SeanBright The repo isn't up-to-date, I'll commit the changes soon..

Comment: @AntonKovalenko where do I add it? (I'm not really familiar with makefiles...)

Comment: @Jay How do I add motor_test.c into the shared object (I don't understand this concept)

Comment: `CSRCS := $(wildcard *.c)` automatically compiles all `*.c` files in the current directory. This avoids the Makefile breaking whenever you add a source file. Yes, it *can* break if you add a source file to the directory but *don't* want it added to the project, but that shouldn't happen as often. Note that ":=" evaluates only once at startup, while "=" evaluates anew at every occurrence of `$(CSRCS)`. This can make some difference, both performance- and functionality-wise.

Comment: Tell me more about the := and = operators, I don't really grasp what you're saying..  
Also, will `$(wildcard *.c)` compile .c files contained in folders? or only the ones that are on the same level in the filesystem hierarchy?

Comment: @DevSolar, wildcards won't work that easily for subdirectories. `$(wildcard */*.c)` might work. `$(shell find . -name '*.c')` is another alternative. Portability goes down with all of these approaches, I believe. Ryuji, wrt. `:=` vs. `=` see [the Flavors section](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html) of the GNU make manual.

Comment: Thanks for the link (regarding `:=` vs `=`). I'll try compiling with the other settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to include all C sources into the `CSRCS` variable of [your `makefile`](http://dt3-robotlego-2012ht-white.googlecode.com/svn/branches/motor/Project12/makefile). Then the build system will know it has to compile that file as well, and include the resulting object into the link.

Comment: I'm getting more and weirder compile errors now..
Let me ask you a general question (set in this specific context).
If I do this:

`# List C source files here.`
<br>(gosh! how do I linebreak..)
`CSRCS   = main.c proc1.c proc2.c proc3.c motor/motor.c`

Will it correctly compile motor.c into an object?

Comment: @Ryuji, can't test here as I don't have an arm gcc here. But from the way `build_files/general.mk` forms `OBJS ?= $(CSRCS:.c=.o) $(ASRCS:.S=.o)` I guess it should, at least if everything works as intended. By the way, there are [no newlines in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197/188688).

Comment: I've tried setting `CSRCS   = main.c proc1.c proc2.c proc3.c motor/motor.c` and also as suggested by DevSolar `CSRCS := $(wildcard *.c)` but this generates a new set of issues (even if I revert to the old setting.. weird). 

Too bad you can't add newlines to comments..

Comment: @Ryuji, you can `make motor/motor.o` to see whether that step works. You probably should add `motor/motor_test.c` to `CSRCS` as well. And give some indication as to what errors you encounter now. Although a new question might be better suited for these.

Comment: I've added all C sources manually, this is how I do it in the outer makefile: `CSRCS   = interrupt/interrupt_tacho.c interrupt/interrupt_timer.c LCD/LCD.c motor/motor.c motor/motor_test.c utils/utils.c main.c proc1.c proc2.c proc3.c`. This seems to work (although there should be a better and more automated way to solve this..)

Comment: Please check r110 of my repo for this solution: https://code.google.com/p/dt3-robotlego-2012ht-white/source/browse/?r=110